# How to prove an isomorphism related to a filtration.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, filtrations

Let $A$ be a filtered algebra with a filtration $F_0(A) \subset F_1(A) \subset \cdots \subset A$. Let $I$ be a two sided ideal of $A$. The algebra $A/I$ has a filtration $F_i(A/I)=F_i(A)/(F_i(A)\cap I)$. In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123069/graded-and-filtered-algebras) it is said that
\begin{align}
F_i(A)/(F_{i-1}(A)+F_i(A) \cap I) \cong \frac{ F_i(A)/(F_i(A) \cap I) }{F_{i-1}(A)/(F_{i-1}(A) \cap I)}.
\end{align}
How to prove this identity? The third isomorphism theorem says that $(A/I)/(B/I)\cong A/B$. But here $F_{i}(A) \cap I \ne F_{i-1}(A) \cap I$. We cannot use the third isomorphism theorem directly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{ F_i(A)/(F_i(A) \cap I) }{F_{i-1}(A)/(F_{i-1}(A) \cap I)}$ is not well-defined since $F_{i-1}(A)/(F_{i-1}(A) \cap I)$ is not a subspace of $F_i(A)/(F_i(A) \cap I)$.

A proof of $\mathrm{gr}(A/I)= \oplus_{i \ge 0} F_i(A)/(F_{i-1}(A) + F_i(A) \cap I)$ is in the following.

\begin{align}
& F_i(A/I) = F_i(A)/(F_{i}(A) \cap I) = (F_i(A) + I)/I, 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
& \mathrm{gr}(A/I) = \oplus_{i \ge 0} F_i(A/I)/F_{i-1}(A/I) \\
& = \oplus_{i \ge 0} ((F_i(A) + I)/I)/((F_{i-1}(A) + I)/I) \\
& = \oplus_{i \ge 0} (F_i(A) + I)/(F_{i-1}(A) + I) \\
& = \oplus_{i \ge 0} F_i(A)/(F_i(A) \cap ( F_{i-1}(A) + I )) \\
& = \oplus_{i \ge 0} F_i(A)/(F_{i-1}(A) + F_i(A) \cap I),
\end{align}
where the second and third isomorphism theorems are used.